# How do I set cookie expiration to "session" in C#?

Tags: c#, session, cookies

Self-Explanatory. In PHP, the solution would be to set the cookie expiration to 0; I'm unsure about C# since it requires a DateTime value.

Comment: Just don't set it to interpret as `Session`

Answer (score 57, accepted):

The docs for [Cookie.Expires](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.cookie.expires%28VS.80%29.aspx) call it right out.

> Setting the Expires property to
>   MinValue makes this a session Cookie,
>   which is its default value.

```
cookie.Expires = DateTime.MinValue
```

Answer (score 5):

This doesn't work for me:

```
cookie.Expires = DateTime.MinValue
```

This does work:

```
cookie.Expires = default(DateTime?)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean any cookie or the session cookie? ASP.NET uses cookie by default for session 'management'.

Either you have the expiry or timeout in the web.config file, or programmatically set it using:
`Session.Timeout = [x]; \\where [x] is in minutes`

This can be called in different ways depending on your needs.

Comment: Expiration session means that cookie lives as long as the browser window with page is open.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to expire the cookie, rather than create a session cookie:

```
cookie.Expires = DateTime.MinValue
```

This creates a session cookie:

```
cookie.Expires = default(DateTime?)
```